# Ubuntu server become unreachable on LAN only

Tags: networking, 18.04, lan

Am running an Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS server.  I can login to it either from my LAN or from the cloud with my router's port forwarding.

After a while of being up and running the server becomes unreachable via the LAN. I cant log into via Putty nor FTP.  And that's from multiple devices I use to login to that server.

However, when this error occurs I can login from the outside, the cloud.

Logs from Putty have no info other than "can't connect."  When this situation occurs I can't even ping the server on it's local IP address.

Rebooting it solves it all, but I have no idea what's causing this.  Seems weird.

Thanks

Comment: @user535733 Thanks, I forgot a sentence

Comment: Since your Ubuntu system (as describe) has no way to tell LAN logins from WAN logins, if the problem were your Ubuntu SSH server, then *all* logins would be locked out. I could be wrong, but I smell a networking problem.

Comment: @user535733 Is there certain log to check the difference?  But again, I can't even ping the thing.  You say a "network" error, would that mean with the machine?  Everything else in my LAN still works.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "check the difference". You can check /var/log/syslog and /var/log/auth for clues.

Comment: @user535733 They're both empty in that they show no failed attempts at all.

Comment: Confirm: When LAN connections and ping fail, WAN connections still work?

Comment: @user535733 Yes!  That's what I find so confounding.  When this error occurs, I then putting in from the WAN side, execute `sudo reboot` and that fixes the problem.  Until it happens again.

Comment: Anyone ever come back to this question?  It's killing me!

Comment: Smells like a dying router or a bad cable to me. But that's just a guess. Since your sever continues to work, and since your server cares not a whit whether connections are LAN vs WAN, I'd suggest looking to elements of the network that do care about LAN vs WAN. But that's outside the scope of AskUbuntu.

Comment: @user535733 I don't think it's the router since to get to it from WAN the router has to properly route from port 80 to the internal IP address.   Which means that the router can reach the internal IP address, while none of my devices (via LAN) can.   And what fixes it is rebooting the server.